# How to check if UITextField's text is valid email?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield

I have a view controller with 3 UITextFields (username, email, and password).

I need a method that checks first, if all fields have text in them, then check if the email's textfield is a valid email, perhaps by checking if it has an `@` sign in it.  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will check a UITextField for a proper email.
Add this method to the [textFields *delegate*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) then check if the characters it is about to change should be added or not.
Return `YES` or `NO` depending on the text fields current text compared to a valid email address:

```
#define ALPHA                   @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#define NUMERIC                 @"1234567890"
#define ALPHA_NUMERIC           ALPHA NUMERIC

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput = nil;
    if ([[textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] count] > 1) {
        unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[ALPHA_NUMERIC stringByAppendingString:@".-"]] invertedSet];
    } else {
        unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[ALPHA_NUMERIC stringByAppendingString:@".!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@"]] invertedSet];
    }
    return ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unacceptedInput] count] <= 1);
}
```

To check if a text field is empty or not just use `if (myTextField.text.length > 0) {}` anywhere in your view controller.

Answer (score 7):

Following code is use for the checking the validation of the email id using the Regex(Regular expresion).

```
(BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; //  return 0;
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used Mimit's solution but modified the emailRegex to allow for longer names such as museum.  So the last curly brackets now says {2, 6} not {2, 4}.  And I tested it with the longer name and it works.  Thanks Mimit for the easy solution.

```
-(BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];    //  return 0;
   return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:-

```
    if(![emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![userNameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {

        NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
        //Valid email address
        if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailTextField.text] == YES) 
        {
    }
    else
    {
    //not valid email address
    }
}


      else
        {
        //any of the text field is empty
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 4.0 or greater, you might also consider [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and do more nuanced checking of the UITextField contents along the lines of [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), for example.